# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php, syntax

I was trying to make a simple registration form in html and php but I get this error message and do not know why:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/daygosta/public_html/dpicollege/register.php on line 47

Here is a link to my code in register.php 
[Click](http://goo.gl/Qj0bR5)

Comment: `<form acti method="POST">` here is typo

Comment: There is a space before the end of your heredoc (`EOT;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this one rather than `heredoc`

```
$form = '
  <form  method="POST">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/></br>
 User Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/></br>
 Email Address: <input type="text" name="email1"/></br>
 Confirm Email Address: <input type="text" name="email2"/></br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/></br>
 Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/></br>
 <input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/></br>
 </form>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that the heredoc is not well closed. Before your  text EOT; can't be any character. In your code I see a tab char.
You can see a big warning in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use '' in your $form variable

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
 $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
 $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
 $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

 if($email1 == $email2){
  if($pass1 == $pass2){
   $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
   $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
   $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
   $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
   $pass = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
   $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);

  }else{
   echo "Sorry , your passwords do not match!</br>";
   exit();
  }
   }else{
  echo "Sorry, your emails do not match!</br>";
   }
 }else{
 $form = '
  <form acti method="POST">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/></br>
 User Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/></br>
 Email Address: <input type="text" name="email1"/></br>
 Confirm Email Address: <input type="text" name="email2"/></br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/></br>
 Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/></br>
 <input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/></br>
 </form>
 ';


 echo $form;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if($email1 == $email2){
        if($pass1 == $pass2){
            $name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']);
            $lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
            $uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
            $email1 = mysql_escape_string($email1);
            $email2 = mysql_escape_string($email2);
            $pass = mysql_escape_string($pass1);
            $pass2 = mysql_escape_string($pass2);

        }else{
            echo "Sorry , your passwords do not match!</br>";
            exit();
        }
    }else{
        echo "Sorry, your emails do not match!</br>";
    }
}else{
    $form = '
  <form acti method="POST">
 First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/></br>
 User Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/></br>
 Email Address: <input type="text" name="email1"/></br>
 Confirm Email Address: <input type="text" name="email2"/></br>
 Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/></br>
 Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/></br>
 <input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/></br>
 </form>
 ';


 echo $form;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is correct as per Heredoc Syntax

```
$form = <<<EOT
    <form acti method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"/></br>
        User Name: <input type="text" name="uname"/></br>
        Email Address: <input type="text" name="email1"/></br>
        Confirm Email Address: <input type="text" name="email2"/></br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="pass1"/></br>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2"/></br>
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/></br>
    </form>
EOT;
```

Comment: read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), Single inverted coma i.e. `'` would not come before and after use of `heredoc syntax` your friend must have upvoted you!! :D

Comment: He's using heredocs son the text <<<EOT and EOT; aren't part of the string

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer ! he want to use heredoc, your error is here  `EOT;` note the  espace before EOT end.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you have white space before the EOT closing, remove this space and your script will work.